# Maven does not use profile properties on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, maven

Suppose I have a profile

```
    <profile>
        <id>ak</id>
        <properties>
            <db.host>localhost</db.host>
            <db.name>ak_cit</db.name>
            <db.user>user</db.user>
            <db.password>pass</db.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

And somewhere in root of pom.xml there are default values

```
<db.host>NOT_DEFINED</db.host>
<db.name>NOT_DEFINED</db.name>
<db.host.reporting.db>NOT_DEFINED</db.host.reporting.db>
<db.name.reporting.db>NOT_DEFINED</db.name.reporting.db>
```

The problem I have while launching my application `mvn -Pak clean install` is that I get an exception because database NOT_DEFINED does not exist. Same command works totally fine on ubuntu or windows. After asking around my co-workers, I've found that some of them are experiencing same problem on OS X.

The only solution which somewhat works for me right now is passing variables through a command line: `-Ddb.host=localhost -Ddb.user=user -Ddb.password=pass -Ddb.name=ak_cit`. The problem with this solution is that there are a lot of properties which need to be passed through.

does anybody knows how to fix this or what might be causing such issue?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Maven on OS X and your other platforms? There may be subtle differences in the way that Maven 2.x and Maven 3.x apply profiles.

Comment: I've just checked on linux and it was maven 3.0.4, while I have 3.1.1 on mac. Tried downgrading and same issue persisted.

Comment: Where have you defined the profile? pom file? settings.xml ?

Comment: Profiles are defined in pom file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in settings.xml.  was overriding my selected profiles. After checking my other systems I've noticed that there were no profiles defined in settings.xml.

Huge help in figuring this out was plugin echoproperties

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <echoproperties />
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```